# Kendo Angular upload "multiple = false" and the button still says "Select Files"

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, upload

Plunker here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/hzH1C1ZGIdyQPcu5kokA?p=info

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'my-upload',
template: `
<kendo-upload
 [saveUrl]="uploadSaveUrl"
 [removeUrl]="uploadRemoveUrl"
 [multiple]="false">
</kendo-upload>
 `
})
export class UploadComponent {
uploadSaveUrl = 'saveUrl'; // should represent an actual API endpoint
uploadRemoveUrl = 'removeUrl';
}
```

The button should really say "Select file..." because you can only select one, so how would I change this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as i know there is no support for pluralization in the upload-component.

The text `Select files...` is just their default-message. (Different translations can be found [here](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular-messages/tree/develop/messages/upload))

But you can override the used message(s) by nesting the `kendo-upload-messages` component within the `kendo-upload` tag. ([API Reference](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/upload/api/CustomMessagesComponent/))

```
<kendo-upload
    ...
>
    <kendo-upload-messages
        select="Select file..."
    >
    </kendo-upload-messages>
</kendo-upload>
```

I've also forked your [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZQTYfmGmA6kq5hZuVvOy?p=preview).